# How to fetch weight variation according to ID and display in a table using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

**This is how my database table looks like:**

| cattle_id | weight | weight_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 300 KG | 01-01-2022 |
| 10002 | 350 KG | 01-01-2022 |
| 10003 | 400 KG | 01-01-2022 |
| 10001 | 310 KG | 15-01-2022 |
| 10002 | 362 KG | 15-01-2022 |
| 10003 | 415 KG | 15-01-2022 |
| 10001 | 318 KG | 30-01-2022 |
| 10002 | 375 KG | 30-01-2022 |
| 10003 | 430 KG | 30-01-2022 |

**I need a query to get the result like below:**

| Cattle ID | Last Weight | 2nd Last Weight | 3rd Last Weight | Remarks | Last Weight Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 318 KG | 310 KG | 300 KG | Not Satisfactory | 30-01-2022 |
| 10002 | 375 KG | 362 KG | 350 KG | Not Satisfactory | 30-01-2022 |
| 10003 | 430 KG | 415 KG | 400 KG | Satisfactory | 30-01-2022 |

*Note: Weight measured after every 15 days & at least 1 KG growth per day is Satisfactory.*

The data is inserted to database properly. I just want to retrieve data like above. How can I acheive this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: *How can I acheive this?* ROW_NUMBER in CTE and conditional aggregation (or 3 table copies) in outer query. To check for Satisfaction use DATEDIFF.

Comment: Thanks @Stu! Lil bit close to my question but in ur recommended answer there is one action column which is already defined. But in my table I have only id and value. I have to fetch the data then display in a table and in one extra column I want to show my remarks.

Comment: Dear @Akina! I have basic knowledge in mysql but I m not an expert. So it will be helpful if u can elaborate ur answer more for my better understanding. Thanks

Comment: #1) Tell us what is your MySQL version (show the output for `SELECT VERSION();`). #2) Replace "This is how my database table looks like" with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: "Last weight date" in expected output doesnot looks correct unless there is some other logic for it, not mentioned in the question. Last weight date for all cattle_id is 30-01-2022.

Comment: Yape that's a mistake @Pankaj. Last weight date for all cattle will be 30-01-2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query can be used -

```
with cte_1 as(
select Cattle_ID,
case 
when (row_number() over (partition by Cattle_ID order by weight_date asc)) = 3 then weight end last_weight,
case when (row_number() over (partition by Cattle_ID order by weight_date asc)) = 2 then weight end 2ndlast_weight,
case when (row_number() over (partition by Cattle_ID order by weight_date asc)) = 1 then weight end 3rdlast_weight,
weight_date
from weight_calc
), cte_2 as (
select cattle_id,max(last_weight) lw, 
max(2ndlast_weight) lw_2,
max(3rdlast_weight) lw_3 ,
max(weight_date) lwd
from cte_1 
group by cattle_id)
select cte_2.cattle_id, 
cte_2.lw as "Last Weight", 
cte_2.lw_2 as "2nd Last Weight", 
cte_2.lw_3 as "3rd Last Weight", 
case when (lw - lw_3)>=30 then "Satisfactory" else "Not satisfactory" end remarks,
cte_2.lwd as "Last Weight"
from cte_2
```

Here is the db [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a327ae36353f6df1dca1e3d751c5e51).

Comment: That is great!! Thanks a lot @Pankaj. I have to make some changes as all my cattles are not weighted after 15 days and new ones are weighted 1 or 2 times but old ones are weighted many times as they stayed for long. I have to figure out to get only the last 3 weight of cattles. Thanks anyway.